# engine mount bolt torque (Ecotec)

Tags: motor-mounts, torque-specification, ecotec

('07 Cobalt LS, 2.2 L)

Re the passenger side engine mounts, ...
The Alldata manual (AIUI, from Helm) says

- Tighten the engine mount to body nuts to 66 N.m (49 lb ft).
- Tighten the engine mount to bracket bolts to 130 N.m (96 lb ft) plus
  45 degrees

But, [specs posted elsewhere](https://www.yourcobalt.com/forums/pr...apacities.html), credibly said to be from GM Global Connect say ...

- Engine Mount to Mid-Rail Nuts 100 N.m
- Engine Mount to Intermediate Bracket Bolts 50 N.m

These seem seriously different, esp 50 Nm vs "130 Nm + 45 degrees".

Does anyone know? Has anyone done "130 Nm + 45 degrees"?  It seems like a lot.

Edit: (Not an answer)  I torqued the bolts to 50 Nm, with thread locker.  So far, doesn't seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my edit into an answer:
I torqued the bolts to 50 Nm, with thread locker. So far, doesn't seem to be a problem.

It felt right, and it's been a couple of years with no apparent problems.

Answer (score 0):

5 degrees seems much too small.. Perhaps it is a typo...

But 45 degrees is more likely, and seen 90 and 120 degrees for some bolts - depends on the design of the bolt and the "stretch" to be accounted for.

Comment: 5 is my typo.  Corrected.  I'm more concerned about the 130 Nm (~100 lb-ft)